# Moment javascript library and javascript date usage when valid times

Tags: javascript, validation, date, time, momentjs

I am currently writing an ASP.NET application (in SharePoint) which requires validation to be performed on fields within a form.  I am currently looking at ways to validate dates and times which include comparing two date times (less than/greater than) and validating formats.

I initially looked at [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) but there has been no updates to that since 2007.  And the last release seemed to be missing two functions according to the docs - isAfter and isBefore - so I switched my attention to using [moment javascript library](http://momentjs.com/).

I currently have a Start Date, Start Time, End Date and End Time text fields - all are required in that way so I do not have Start DateTime and EndDateTime - which the user enters input into.  I am also using jQuery Date Picker and [jquery-ui-timepicker-addon](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker/) to select dates and times.

One issue I have is when entering a time into a time field, I can enter the following:

11:90 - this will adjust to 11:59.

11:100 - which does not adjust.

This is where I am feeding the values into my custom validation javascript function to validate the time.  This is done using the following code:

```
function ValidateTimeFormat(objSource, objArgs) {
    var strToCompare = objArgs.Value;
    var timeFormat = 'HH:mm';
    var expectedEndDateObj = moment(strToCompare, timeFormat);
    objArgs.IsValid = expectedEndDateObj.isValid();
}
```

With ASP.NET snippet:

```
<div class="label-div">
    <asp:Label ID="StartTimeLabel" runat="server" Text="Actual Start Time:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ActualStartTimeRequiredValidator" 
        runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="StartTimeTextBox"
        ErrorMessage="Actual start time is required field" 
        Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="ActualStartTimeCustomValidator" 
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="StartTimeTextBox"
        ErrorMessage="Actual start time format is not correct" 
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTimeFormat">*</asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartTimeTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></li>
```

According to momentjs (if I remove the jQuery Time Picker):

- 11:90 is invalid.
- 11:100 is valid.

I have not seen any forums or support for momentjs so thought I would ask on here.  There are countless ways to validate times including using regex in your own custom validation routines - but I do not want to reinvent the wheel at the moment.  I would like a nice library to use to do it.

Just to quote the momentjs docs for validation [isValid](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/):

The main `moment()` function is very flexible and will allow overflowing in parsing input. For example, `moment("2012-01-40", "YYYY-MM-DD")` will overflow the date value into the months, making the actual moment Feb 9 (31 days in Jan + 9 days into Feb).

This can be useful when getting things like the 150th day of the year, or the 500th minute in a day, however, it can be problematic when trying to parse user input.

moment#isValid was added to check if the input for a moment is indeed a valid date.

Given that the library is a wrapper around Date I am not sure if this is a javascript issue or with moment - or indeed myself!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please read: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its an issue with moment. As of moment 2.3.0 you can try using strict parsing as mentioned here - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

However I still find moment parser considers times like "01:k0 A" valid for "hh:mm A"